# Accessing Express request object with a variable across all routes

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

Relative newbie here,

I have built a shop website with a shopping cart, using express-session to retain the user's cart as they add items and proceed to the checkout.

I'm accessing and manipulating the cart using 'req.session.cart' within middleware/routes in my app.js file, with the user's session stored on MongoDB session store.

My question is that for some of the routes, I want to do things with some of the data in the cart object, and find myself declaring variables inside the routes as below... here is my code:

```
const cartModel = {
  items: [],
  totals: {
    qty: 0,
    price: 0
  },
};

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  if (!req.session.cart) {
    req.session.cart = cartModel;
    req.session.save(()=>{
      next();
    });
  } else {
  next();
};
});

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
const totalPrice = req.session.cart.totals.price;
//some other stuff
});

app.get("/checkout", (req, res)=>{
const totalPrice = req.session.cart.totals.price;
//some other stuff
});
```

Basically, I want to know if there is a way to set that 'totalPrice' variable globally or otherwise, so that I can refer to it without needing to declare it within every route. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this is important to you, my recommendation would be to add middleware to give you a somewhat more compact way to access the price, something like this:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.totalPrice = req?.session?.cart?.totals?.price;
  next();
});

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
  const { totalPrice } = req;
  //some other stuff
});

app.get("/checkout", (req, res)=>{
  const { totalPrice } = req;
  //some other stuff
});
```

Of course, it *is* possible to assign the price to a global variable, but not really in a way that supports concurrency. `req` is the context of the current request, and there may be many requests being processed by the server at any given time, so if there were a `totalPrice` in the global scope, it would be unclear which request's price it is unless you jump through hoops that will just make your life harder.

I don't think there's any particular problem with just having `const totalPrice = req.session.cart.totals.price;` in each route that needs to look at it.

Comment: Thanks so much! That's basically it - I want a more compact way of accessing certain nested properties, and also - if possible - a way to do it across all routes where I need to access those properties, without the redundancy of assigning to a variable in every route.